# Gmail SignUp/LogIn using Curl/Php

Tags: php

This is an old question and have been answered,  but the answers are outdated.

Is it possible? What is the best alternative?

I only want to fill the signup/login forms as complicated as google's, using my site.

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommended trying to login to gmail through CURL, it even might be a violation of their terms (please check, it is a wild guess). Please, try using gmail api

https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/

with it you can:

- Read messages from Gmail
- Send email messages
- Modify the labels applied to messages and threads
- Search for specific messages and threads